# Laravel - Dependent Dropdown Error: GET http://localhost:8888/get.employee.states?country_id=5 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

In Laravel-5.8, I'm trying to load state from a selected country.

The HrEmployeesController is in a folder called Hr

Controller

```
class HrEmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function getStateList(Request $request)
    {
        $states = DB::table("config_states")
                ->where("country_id",$request->country_id)
                ->pluck("state_name","id")
                ->sortByDesc('state_name');
        return response()->json($states);
    }
}
```

view

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Country:</label>
        <select id="country" class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Country" tabindex="1" name="country_id" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Country</option>
            @if($countries->count() > 0 )
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->country_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>   
<!-- /.col -->
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> State:</label>
        <select id="state" class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose State" tabindex="1" name="state_id" style="width: 100%;">
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#country').change(function(){
    var countryID = $(this).val();    
    if(countryID){
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"{{url('get.employee.states')}}?country_id="+countryID,
           success:function(res){               
               if(res){
                   $("#state").empty();
                   $("#state").append('<option>Select</option>');
                   $.each(res,function(key,value){
                       $("#state").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                   });
               }else{
                   $("#state").empty();
               }
           }
       });
   }else{
       $("#state").empty();
       $("#city").empty();
   }      
});
$('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val();    
    if(stateID){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"{{url('get.employee.cities')}}?state_id="+stateID,
            success:function(res){               
                if(res){
                    $("#city").empty();
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $("#city").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
                }else{
                    $("#city").empty();
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#city").empty();
    }
});
</script>
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'hr', 'as' => 'hr.', 'namespace' => 'Hr', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::delete('employees/destroy', 'HrEmployeesController@massDestroy')->name('employees.massDestroy');
    Route::resource('employees', 'HrEmployeesController');
});

Route::get('get/getStateList','Hr\HrEmployeesController@getStateList')->name('get.employee.states');
Route::get('get/getCityList','Hr\HrEmployeesController@getCityList')->name('get.employee.cities');
```

When I selected a country to load the states in the state dropdown, I got this error:

> GET http://localhost:8888/get.employee.states?country_id=5 404 (Not Found)

How do I get this sorted out?

Thank you.

Comment: There are no url in your route called `get.employee.states`

Comment: @TalhaF. - Its there. See it here .      Route::get('get/getStateList','Hr\HrEmployeesController@getStateList')->name('get.employee.states');

Comment: You misspelled `route` and `url`. `get.employee.states` is a name route, not url. Change `{{ url('get.employee.cities') }}` to `{{ url('get/getStateList') }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `get.employee.states` is a named route So change your url in ajax  from

```
url:"{{url('get.employee.states')}}?country_id="+countryID,
```

> **to**

```
   url:"{{route('get.employee.states')}}?country_id="+countryID,
```